# Create VolatileImage always return null

Tags: java, image, swing, java-2d

I am creating a volatile image in the following class, but hitting a NullPointerException every time. The reason why createVolatileImage() is returning null (from its JavaDoc) is that GraphicsEnvironment.isHeadless() is true.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.VolatileImage;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Tube extends JPanel {

    private VolatileImage image;
    private int width, height;

    public Tube() {
        super(true);
    }

    public Tube(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        createImage();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if(image == null)
            createImage();
        if(image.validate(getGraphicsConfiguration()) == VolatileImage.IMAGE_INCOMPATIBLE)
            createImage();
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_LCD_HRGB);
        g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
    }

    public VolatileImage getBufferedImage() {
        return this.image;
    }

    private void createImage(){
        if(image != null){
            image.flush();
            image = null;
        }
        image = createVolatileImage(width, height);
        image.setAccelerationPriority(1.0f);
    }
}
```

How can I return a non-null VolatileImage ??

Comment: Why not use `java.awt.image.BufferedImage` instead?

Comment: well I have a BufferedImage implementation ... I want to benchmark these two implementations on different platforms.

Comment: Hang on, are you actually running headless? If so, then you've already answered your own question...

Comment: well I don't know what that mean, or suppose to indicate? how can I change that headless state ???

Comment: [Here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/headless/) is one explanation. But...are you running headless or you're not sure?

Comment: Not sure at all what headless suppose to mean in Swing, but I'm going to check out the link .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would change the headless mode:

```
System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "false");
```

Comment: True, and it should be false by default. However, `createVolatileImage` can still return null if the component is not displayable (see my answer).

Comment: yes I tried to remove it from the constructor as you said, but that didn't change anything.. anyway my benchmark showed that using VolatileImage didn't make any difference. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the same method createImage() in three different pre-conditions.

1) When the constructor is called

2) When the image field is null

3) When the image field is not null

Your problem might lie in the implementation of the createImage() method.

Comment: well no, I'm following this implementation: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/chet/archive/2003/09/volatileimage_n.html

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include a stacktrace, but is the exception thrown from the constructor? If so, this is probably happening because the component is not displayable yet, so `createVolatileImage` may return `null`. Try removing the `createImage` call from the constructor.

Comment: The exception is thrown when i first try to access image, I will try your suggestion.